# Wamp not working after upgrading to windows 10

Tags: apache, wamp

When i upgraded my pc to Windows 10, wamp server doesn't work anymore (All i get is the orange icon and not the green).

First, I've tested port 80, it was used by iis 10, so i changed to port 8080 in the httpd.conf and then restart all services, icon still orange.

Second, I opened windows features and disable Internet Information Service, restarted my pc, icon still orange.

1- What should I do to fix it? 
2- Is it good to disable iis?

Answer (score 0):

after upgrade to windows 10 iis auto start you need stop it and disable this service 
open cmd and type net start W3SVC  then enter for stop iis after start wamp server

for disable service open services and find some thing like "World Wide Web Services" and properties and choose disable